# Solution to a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given three functions $z'(t), y'(t), x'(t)$ and I have reduced these functions to the equation:
\begin{equation}
z''=x_{0}\beta z'e^{-\frac{\beta}{\gamma}z} - \gamma z
\end{equation}
where $\beta, \gamma ,x_{0}$ are constants.
Next we introduce a new function:
\begin{equation}
u(t)=e^{-\frac{\beta}{\gamma}z}
\end{equation}
Substitution yields
\begin{equation}
u\frac{d^{2}u}{dt^{2}}- \bigg(\frac{du}{dt}\bigg)^{2}+(\gamma - x_{0}\beta u)u\frac{du}{dt} = 0 
\end{equation}
Next a new function is introduced:
\begin{equation}
\phi = \frac{dt}{du}
\end{equation}
Now the equation can be rearranged to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\phi}{du}+\frac{1}{u} \phi = (\gamma-x_{0}\beta u )\phi^{2}
\end{equation}
The solution to this equation is:
\begin{equation}
\phi = \frac{1}{u(C_{1}-\gamma \ln u +x_{0}\beta u)}
\end{equation}
So what would be the solution to the original equation in terms of $u$?

Comment: The ordinary differential equation (ODE) that you write down for $u$ is equivalent to $z'' = x_0 \beta z' e^{-\frac{\beta}{\gamma} z} - \gamma z'$. So there is either a mistake in the original ODE for $z$ or in the ODE for $u$. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

The last equation od
$$
\frac{dt}{du}=\frac{1}{u(C_{1}-\gamma \ln u +x_{0}\beta\, u)}.
$$
Integrating
$$
t=\int\frac{du}{u(C_{1}-\gamma \ln u +x_{0}\beta\, u)}.
$$
I do not think that there is a closed formula for the integral.